# Append last array element in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to add a newline to the last element of an array
I have tried this:

```
$array[-1] .= "\n";
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1
```

I have tried a few other methods as well (without `.=`), without success.
Should I try `splice`?

example of what i want :

```
@array = (
  "one",
  "two",
  "n",
  "last\n",  # i want the newline to be added here
);
```

Comment: Question is why you want to add a newline there. I sense an XY-problem. Is this related to printing the array?

Comment: i wanted to try something as i am using a module to write in Excel files and certain routines expect a newline at the end to ensure that the cell has wrapping enabled.

Comment: So that's a no. You should ask the question you really wanted answered, not a fake question which has nothing to do with the thing you really wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$array[-1] .= "\n";` to change last entry but make sure you are checking if array is not empty.

Error message `Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1` has a pretty good explanation [here](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/perl/perldoc/manual/perldiag.html):

> You tried to make an array value spring into existence, and the
> subscript was probably negative, even counting from end of the array
> backwards.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
  "one",
  "two",
  "n",
  "last",
);

print Dumper(\@array);

if ($#array != -1) {
    $array[-1] .= "\n";
}

print Dumper(\@array);
```

EDIT: As it was correctly mentioned in comments, the problem was not necessarily using `-1` instead of `$#array` as both of those will access last value, but missing if statement checking if array is empty, answer was adjusted to remove unnecessary comment that might be misleading so it is more focused on the actual reason for error.

Comment: thank you for taking the time writing the message, but i am getting the exact error message. is strict/warning blocking it maybe ? i'll without

Comment: What Perl version are you running? I am using script and it is working.

Comment: oh that was indeed related to the fact that i had one empty array in my loop, thank you !

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for pointing out what I communicated poorly in my answer!

Answer (score 3):

`$array[-1]` is the last element of the array.

But what's the last element of an empty array? This unclear message is the result of trying to modify the last element of an empty array.

```
$ perl -e'my @a = qw( a b c ); $a[-1] .= "\n";'

$ perl -e'my @a;               $a[-1] .= "\n";'
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at -e line 1.
```

You can check if the an array is nonempty using `if ( @array )`.

Comment: thanks for adding an answer and yes i didn't think that my array could be empty so i fixed it afterwards. i believe i could simply do $array[-1] .= "\n" if @array; which will fix the problem